# Why does Perl's DBIx::Class $resultset->update fail on complex search queries?

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

I have a Perl [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class) search the looks like this:

```
my $rs = shift->search( {
      -and => [
            { 'for_revocation' => 1 },
            [
                { 
                     status => { 
                        'not_in' => [ 'revoked', 'revoking'] 
                    },
                },
                {   
                    status => 'revoking',
                    updated => { 
                        '<' => \'now() - interval 1 hour' 
                    }
                },
            ]
        ]
    });
```

and then I do ..

```
$rs->update({ status => 'revoked' });
```

But I get the error ...

> DBI Exception: DBD::mysql::st execute
>   failed: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FOR REVOCATION '1' )' at line 1
>   [for Statement "UPDATE wmv_attempt SET
>   status = ? WHERE ( ARRAY(0xadf93a8)
>   FOR REVOCATION ? )" with ParamValues:
>   0='revoking', 1=1] at (eval 20938)
>   line 1

If I use `$rs->as_query()` to get the SQL used to do the search it looks like this:

```
SELECT .... FROM wmv_attempt me WHERE ( ( ( status NOT IN ( ?, ? ) OR ( status = ? AND 
updated < now() - interval 1 hour ) ) AND for_revocation = ? ) )
```

Which works fine.

It seems that when it does the `update()` on the resultset it fails to be able to create the WHERE clause correctly.

I suspect this is a bug.

Can anyone suggest something I might be doing wrong or an alternative approach?

Thanks, Tom

Comment: Can you confirm whether the resultset works except for the update() bit?   Also can you mention what versions of Perl, DBIx::Class, SQL::Abstract, DBI, DBD::MySQL and MySQL your using.

Comment: Yes the resultset works fine. I managed to fix it with help from guys on irc 'dbix-class' by using -or => []. They have noted it as a bug to fix for the next version.

Comment: You should submit an answer to your own question and accept it so that the question isn't on the "unanswered" list :)